Cross-compile the Wazuh agent
I am trying to cross-compile the Wazuh agent. I am using Debian 12 (amd64) and want to install the Wazuh agent on an STM32MP157F-DK2 (arm32). I downloaded the source code on my host machine from https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-agent. In the src folder, I ran:
make deps
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- TARGET=agent

After successfully building, I get message:
Done building agent

Can you please tell me where the binary files are located so that I can execute them on the STM32MP157F-DK2?
symeon@debian:~/Desktop/wazuh-4.8.1/src$ ls -l
total 23844
drwxr-xr-x  3 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:56 active-response
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:56 addagent
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   242368 Αυγ  13 15:55 agent-auth
drwxr-xr-x  3 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 agentlessd
drwxr-xr-x  8 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 analysisd
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon     7373 Ιουλ 17 14:54 build.py
drwxr-xr-x  4 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 ci
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 client-agent
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon     4914 Ιουλ 17 14:54 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 config
drwxr-xr-x  8 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:53 data_provider
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    27208 Αυγ  13 15:56 default-firewall-drop
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23096 Αυγ  13 15:56 disable-account
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon   106131 Ιουλ 17 14:54 Doxyfile
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 error_messages
drwxr-xr-x 29 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 14:02 external
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23104 Αυγ  13 15:56 firewalld-drop
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 generated_headers
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 headers
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23128 Αυγ  13 15:56 host-deny
drwxr-xr-x  4 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 init
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23112 Αυγ  13 15:56 ip-customblock
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23096 Αυγ  13 15:56 ipfw
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23080 Αυγ  13 15:56 kaspersky
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon   125312 Αυγ  13 15:53 libgcc_s.so.1
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon   113956 Αυγ  13 15:55 librootcheck.a
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon  2190440 Αυγ  13 15:53 libstdc++.so.6
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon  2163166 Αυγ  13 15:55 libwazuh.a
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon 15228568 Αυγ  13 15:53 libwazuhext.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   182048 Αυγ  13 15:56 libwazuhshared.so
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 logcollector
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon   104394 Ιουλ 17 14:54 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   245200 Αυγ  13 15:56 manage_agents
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 monitord
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23088 Αυγ  13 15:56 npf
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 os_auth
drwxr-xr-x 13 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 os_crypto
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 os_csyslogd
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 os_dbd
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:56 os_execd
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 os_integrator
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 os_maild
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 os_net
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 os_regex
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 os_xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 os_zlib
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 14:55 output
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23120 Αυγ  13 15:56 pf
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon    20102 Ιουλ 17 14:54 Readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 remoted
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 reportd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23088 Αυγ  13 15:56 restart-wazuh
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon        6 Ιουλ 17 14:54 REVISION
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 rootcheck
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23096 Αυγ  13 15:56 route-null
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 selinux
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:56 shared
drwxr-xr-x 11 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:59 shared_modules
drwxr-xr-x  6 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 syscheckd
drwxr-xr-x 28 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 unit_tests
drwxr-xr-x  2 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 util
-rw-r--r--  1 symeon symeon        7 Ιουλ 17 14:54 VERSION
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   818032 Αυγ  13 15:55 wazuh-agentd
drwxr-xr-x  3 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:55 wazuh_db
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   785416 Αυγ  13 15:56 wazuh-execd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   827152 Αυγ  13 15:55 wazuh-logcollector
drwxr-xr-x  6 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 15:56 wazuh_modules
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon   758136 Αυγ  13 15:56 wazuh-modulesd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 symeon symeon    23080 Αυγ  13 15:56 wazuh-slack
drwxr-xr-x  6 symeon symeon     4096 Αυγ  13 13:55 win32

P.S. The STM32MP157F-DK2 does not have gcc/g++, only make and cmake.
